# Google analytics regex issue

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Im having an issue with my funnel which i have set up using regex. The end goal has to match a url such as booking/oxford/458752/confirmation.

The number in the URL is the order number.

My funnel destination is booking/oxford/\d+/confirmation$

Step 1 - */booking/oxford/\d+/*

Step 2 - */Booking/oxford/\d+/booking/select-tickets*

Step 3 - */Booking/oxford/\d+/booking/select-seats*

Step 4 - */Booking/oxford/\d+/booking/payment*

The funnel is showing URLs such as

*/Booking/oxford/7737/booking/select-tickets*

as been drop outs at step 1 even though this should match step 2?

Im not great with regex so any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try this service to test regex https://regex101.com. And keep in mind that match type for goal is the same as for steps: equals to, begins with or regex.